# cs50 pset5 why does my image recovery program only recover 49 of 50 images?

Tags: c, image, jpeg, recovery, cs50

So my recover.c program works well, except for the fact that it fails to recover ALL 50 images from the [card.raw](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwu73vgy_kGoODVKdkpIWDhiMkk/view?usp=sharing) file.

I can only get it to recover 49 of the 50 images. I'm pretty sure the missing image is the very first image (a girl with in a snowy background) because I saw that image early on in the process of writing and testing but the final program doesnt seem to recover that image anymore.

Any help guys?

```
  /**
 * recover.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 4
 *
 * Recovers JPEGs from a forensic image.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t  LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;

typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;



int main(void)
{
    // OPEN CARD FILE
    char* infile = "card.raw";

    FILE* card = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (card == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", "card.raw");
        return 2;
    }

    int f = 0, c = 0, imageno = 0;
    // c signals that a jpg is being written
    FILE* images;
    char title[25];
    BYTE buffer[512];

    /*repeat until end of card*/
    do
    {
        //read one block into buffer

        fread(buffer, 512, 1, card);

        if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff)
        {
            if (imageno < 10)
            {
                sprintf(title, "00%d.jpg", imageno); //change jpg title
            }
            else
            {
                sprintf(title, "0%d.jpg", imageno); //change jpg title
            }

            if (f == 1) //close previous jpg
            {
                fclose(images);
                imageno++;
            }

            images = fopen(title, "w");
            f = 1; //very first jpg has been opened
            c = 1; //jpg open
        }
        //jpg already open?
        if (c == 1) fwrite(buffer, 512, 1, images);
    }    
    while (!feof(card));
    return 0;
        //close any remaining files
}
```

Comment: Consider a single `sprintf(title, "%03d.jpg", imageno)` instead of the two `sprintf()` calls you're using now.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for that!

Comment: Check the return values of your function calls --e.g. `fread()` -- for error codes or unexpected results.

Comment: `} while (!feof(card));` is bad. It means you have already processed an illegal read. Noticeable by its absence is any check (or use) of the return value from `fread`. There are loads of questions on SO about recovering images from card.

Comment: change the `do...while()` loop into a `while( fread(...) ) { ... }` loop.  Do NOT control any loop via the function: `feof()`

Comment: when calling the function: `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the code is assuming that each image is 512 bytes long. (that is a mighty small image) .   Suggest using the returned value from the call to `fread()` to determine how many bytes to write to the new file.  Suggest eliminate the variables `f` and `c`.  initialize variable `images` to NULL, then check for `not NULL` as a reason to call fclose on a file.  Always check the returned value from `fopen()` to assure the call was successful.  the code will only write to the new file if the beginning of the buffer[0...2] is not 0xffd8ff.  Probably not what you want. Suggest place write inside loop

Comment: the posted code has a comment: `close any remaining files`  1) that has to be done before the call to `return;`  2) again, check `images` for not NULL before calling `fclose()` on a final file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a file name based on the value of variable `imageno`.  You later increment that variable, but only in the event that that your program opened another file previously.  In particular, you do not increment it after opening the very first file, therefore the same name is computed for the second file as was computed for the first, and the first file extracted gets overwritten.

You should unconditionally increment `imageno` each time you create a new file name, or maybe each time you open a file.

Comment: You sir, are a true hero.